# Find the area of the region in the plane bounded by the curves

Tags: calculus

[image]

$$\frac1{3}\int_{\sqrt3}^3\frac1{x^2(x^2+9)^{1/2}}dx=\frac1{3}\int\frac1{(\sec^2\theta )9\tan^2\theta(9\sec^2\theta)^{1/2}}=\frac1{81}\int\frac{\cos^5\theta}{\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$
This is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> $$I=\int_{\sqrt3}^3\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+9}}$$

Let $t=1/x,dt=-dx/x^2$
So:
$$\int_{1/\sqrt3}^{1/3}\frac{-tdt}{\sqrt{9t^2+1}}=\frac{-1}{18}\int_{1/\sqrt3}^{1/3}\frac{18tdt}{\sqrt{9t^2+1}}=-\frac2{18}\sqrt{9t^2+1}|_{1/\sqrt3}^{1/3}=\frac{-2}{18}(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{4})=\frac{2-\sqrt2}9$$

---

**Added Later:**

Let $x=3\tan\theta,dx=3\sec^2\theta d\theta$
$$I=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}\frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{9\tan^2\theta\sec\theta}=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{9\sin^2\theta}$$
Let $t=\sin\theta,dt=\cos\theta d\theta$
$$I=\int_{1/2}^{1/\sqrt2}\frac{dt}{9t^2}=\left(-\frac1{9t}\right)_{1/2}^{1/\sqrt2}=\frac{2-\sqrt2}9$$

---

**Added Still Later:**
$$I=\int_{\sqrt3}^3\frac19\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{x^2}-\frac1{\sqrt{9+x^2}}\right)dx$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this problem requires that trig substitution be used to answer the question. I understand how you have solved it here, but I need to do it a different way.

Comment: @mmm edited....